# How to split a two-dimensional array into different pieces and combine them into a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

here is the code

```
v_in = 2.5
v_out = 25
v_step = 0.5
row = len(np.arange(v_in, v_out+v_step, v_step))
Cp = [0.489, 0.4, 0.452, 0.45]
Cp_set = np.zeros((row, len(Cp)+1))
Cp_set[:,0] = np.arange(v_in, v_out+v_step, v_step)

for i in range(len(Cp)):
    v_rate = (7150*1000/(0.5*1.225*195**2*Cp[i]/4))**(1/3)
    v_rate_index = np.ceil(v_rate/v_step)*v_step
    x = [Cp_set[int(v_rate_index)-10:int(v_rate_index)-5, 0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index):row, 0]]
    print(x)
```

the result is below

```
[array([4.5, 5. , 5.5, 6. , 6.5]), array([ 9.5, 10. , 10.5, 11. , 11.5, 12. , 12.5, 13. , 13.5, 14. , 14.5,  15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5, 20. ,  20.5, 21. , 21.5, 22. , 22.5, 23. , 23.5, 24. , 24.5, 25. ])]
```

how did I get what I want as below

```
[4.5, 5. , 5.5, 6. , 6.5,  9.5, 10. , 10.5, 11. , 11.5, 12. , 12.5, 13. , 13.5, 14. , 14.5,  15. , 15.5, 16. , 16.5, 17. , 17.5, 18. , 18.5, 19. , 19.5, 20. ,  20.5, 21. , 21.5, 22. , 22.5, 23. , 23.5, 24. , 24.5, 25.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation:

```
import numpy as np

v_in = 2.5
v_out = 25
v_step = 0.5
row = len(np.arange(v_in, v_out+v_step, v_step))
Cp = [0.489, 0.4, 0.452, 0.45]
Cp_set = np.zeros((row, len(Cp)+1))
Cp_set[:,0] = np.arange(v_in, v_out+v_step, v_step)

for i in range(len(Cp)):
    v_rate = (7150*1000/(0.5*1.225*195**2*Cp[i]/4))**(1/3)
    v_rate_index = np.ceil(v_rate/v_step)*v_step
    x = np.concatenate([[0],Cp_set[int(v_rate_index)-10:int(v_rate_index)-5, 0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index):row, 0]])
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5  9.5 10.  10.5 11.  11.5 12.  12.5 13.
 13.5 14.  14.5 15.  15.5 16.  16.5 17.  17.5 18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.
 20.5 21.  21.5 22.  22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25. ]
[ 0.   5.   5.5  6.   6.5  7.  10.  10.5 11.  11.5 12.  12.5 13.  13.5
 14.  14.5 15.  15.5 16.  16.5 17.  17.5 18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.  20.5
 21.  21.5 22.  22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25. ]
[ 0.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5  9.5 10.  10.5 11.  11.5 12.  12.5 13.
 13.5 14.  14.5 15.  15.5 16.  16.5 17.  17.5 18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.
 20.5 21.  21.5 22.  22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25. ]
[ 0.   4.5  5.   5.5  6.   6.5  9.5 10.  10.5 11.  11.5 12.  12.5 13.
 13.5 14.  14.5 15.  15.5 16.  16.5 17.  17.5 18.  18.5 19.  19.5 20.
 20.5 21.  21.5 22.  22.5 23.  23.5 24.  24.5 25. ]
```

Comment: If you think the answer is right, please mark the answer right, as it may be helpful in the future.

Answer (score -1):

you need to flatten your list like so :

```
for i in range(len(Cp)):
    v_rate = (7150*1000/(0.5*1.225*195**2*Cp[i]/4))**(1/3)
    v_rate_index = np.ceil(v_rate/v_step)*v_step
    x = [Cp_set[int(v_rate_index)-10:int(v_rate_index)-5, 0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index):row, 0]]
    flatten_list = [element for sublist in x for element in sublist]
    print(flatten_list)
```

Output : [4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0]

Comment: many thanks for your answer, then if I add an element in x, like below                                                        x = [0, Cp_set[int(v_rate_index)-10:int(v_rate_index)-5, 0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index):row, 0]]                                        how did I get                       [0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0, 23.5, 24.0, 24.5, 25.0]

Comment: Why are you trying to increase complexity of code with n^2 complexity.

Comment: because I need to get a list to caculate, such as interp1d...

Comment: use code of @KedarUShet and add the 0 to the beginning like this: `np.concatenate([[0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index)-10:int(v_rate_index)-5, 0], Cp_set[int(v_rate_index):row, 0]])`

Comment: @李小孟 please rephrase your question if you need List rather than array.

Comment: oh, many thanks, you sloved my question! good luck with you!